# How to retrieve indentity column vaule after insert using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Could any of you please show me how to complete the following tasks?

```
// Prepare object to be saved
// Note that MasterTable has MasterTableId as a Primary Key and it is an indentity column

MasterTable masterTable = new MasterTable();
masterTable.Column1 = "Column 1 Value";
masterTable.Column2 = 111;

// Instantiate DataContext
DataContext myDataContext = new DataContext("<<ConnectionStrin>>");

// Save the record
myDataContext.MasterTables.InsertOnSubmit(masterTable);
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();

// ?QUESTION?
// Now I need to retrieve the value of MasterTableId for the record just inserted above.
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identity value is assigned to the inserted object just after you call SubmitChanges.

Just access:

```
masterTable.MasterTableId
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that LINQ to SQL automatically wraps all changes in a database transaction. So if I wanted to use the returned ID for another insert (my user table has an AddressID, so I add a new Address record and then add a new user record with that ID) and there was a problem inserting a user, the address insert would not roll back. Should you wrap both SubmitChanges in another transaction?